# Select points falling into a shapefile

Tags: qgis

I am quite new to GIS so I am sorry for my "primitive" vocabulary. 
In QGIS, I have a set of points falling in specific coordinates in Africa and Europe. 
I would like to select only those points which are within the continents (thus not in the sea).

Probably the figure is more explanative :

[image: figure]

I have tried to use the intersection feature but it is not working as the only result I am obtaining is the only point which is actually falling perfectly onto a line (see image. I have made the point bigger just to visualize it better).

Can you help me with this?

[image].png

Comment: It seem that your "land" layer is only line (ie there is no inside so nothing to intersect) you need to either polygonise your layer or find a layer that is already made of polygon. With point and polygon you then can use the "select by location" tool in the processing toolbox

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue and select all the points falling within Europe. 
What I did was first to select all the european countries "touched" by the points and create a new shapefile. Then I have used again the "select by location" tool to take all the points within the selected countruies. Probably not the fastest solution but it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Export the Europe shapefile (**Right click on the layer - Export**) to CRS:4326. After use the **Geoprocessing Tools / Clip** algorithm. As input, use your point layer, and the polygon layer as clip layer.

Comment: I have tried your soulution but I have an error when running the clip.

It says (I am translating from Italian): "the element (2) has a not valid geometry. Correct the geometry or change processing settings in "ignore not valid input geometries""

Comment: Hmm, there is a geometric problem with the Europe layer, maybe comes from the multipolygons. Explode the multpart polygons with the following method: Vector / Geometry Tools / Multipart to singleparts

Comment: Ok I have followed your suggestion but I could not see any differnce on the map of Europe. Please could you explain more about the issue, the possible causes and the ways to solve it?
Thanks,

Comment: You won't see any difference, just try to clip with the new Europe layer.

Comment: Shapefiles can become corrupt for a variety of reasons.  Sometimes the corruption is not noticeable until the shapefile is used in a particular operation, such as a buffer or overlay.  QGIS has "Check Geometry" and "Repair Geometry" tools that may fix your shapefile problem.